# Tkinter restore button

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: Maximized]
[image: Restored]
I want to be able to control the default restored size of my windows when click the restore button of the window itself. Right now whenever I click the restore button it stays with the maximized size which is the screen resolution but it just moves to the right a little bit. I want in a way that I can set up a default size before dragging it smaller or bigger depending on the desired size. I attached my code for reference

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from pathlib import Path
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


filename = None
file_path = None
files = [
    ('All Files', '*.*'),
    ('Python Files', '*.py'),
    ('Text Document', '*.txt')
]


def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)


def saveFile():
    global filename
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f = open(file_path, mode='w')
        f.write(t)
        f.close()
    except:
        saveAs()


def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', initialdir="C:\\Users\\charl/Documents", filetypes=files, defaultextension=".txt")
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    f.write(t)
    # except:
    #     f.showerror(title="Oops!", message="Unable to save file...")


def openFile():
    global filename, file_path
    f = askopenfile(mode='r')
    filename = Path(f.name).stem
    file_path = f.name
    t = f.read()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, t)
    f.close()


root = Tk()
root.title("My Python Text Editor")
root.state('zoomed')
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=GetSystemMetrics(0), height=GetSystemMetrics(1))
text = Text(root, width=400, height=400)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

menubar = Menu(root)
file = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As...", command=saveAs)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit())
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because the `text` box (400 characters x 400 lines) is larger than the `minsize`.  The `width` and `height` options of `Text` widget are not in pixels.

Comment: I edited my post to explain my situation clearer. I want the window so that it really becomes smaller when restore is clicked

Comment: As I said in my first comment, the `text` box is too large.  Try removing the `width` and `height` options from `text = Text(...)`, i.e. `text = Text(root)`.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!! I've been searching for hours. I'm new here so I don't know what to do when my question is already answered.

Comment: I have added my suggestion as answer that you can accept to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `text` box is too large.  Try removing the `width` and `height` options from `text = Text(...)` like below:

```
text = Text(root)
```